Chrome extension – Set specific icon for development (local) and production
I have just started Chrome development. I understand everything runs through the manifest.json file.
I have both production and development extension installed. However, I want to change the icons depending on whether its production or development. This will help me visually distinguish what version I am testing with.
How can I achieve this?
Currently below are my icons thats used for both production and development
manifest.json
"icons": {
 "32": "favicon-32x32.png",
 "48": "favicon-48x48.png",
 "128": "favicon-128x128.png"
},


The declaration of a set of icons in manifest.json must be static.
I think there is no chance to change at runtime (so even at installation time) the contextMenu icon as the bigger icon normally used in extensions page.
If you want to change only the action icon at installation time according to production or development environment you should  check first an extension property like the "id" or the "key" and then use chrome.action.setIcon method with 2 distinct icons.
